# Avoid reassigning parameters

Tags: java, pmd

I’m getting PMD red colored violation

Avoid reassigning parameters such as 'bankRequest'

This is my method

```
   @Override
public BankDTO loadTariff(BankDTO bankRequest, int[] executionLevels) {
    double[] fee = null;
    for (int level : executionLevels) {

        // Check the tariff availability from execution level one to .....
        fee = loadCokaAndBankFee(bankRequest,level);

        if (fee != null) { // if fee found reload the bank request with new
                            // amount
            bankRequest = reloadBankRequest(bankRequest, fee);
            break; // no need to go for any other level deep level cover //
                    // here.
        } // if tariff not found use the esb provided amounts
    }

    return bankRequest;
}
```

Could someone explain what wrong with this code. If I ignore it what is the impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid re assigning variables for the reasons already given. Anyway,instead of assigning a new variable consider just returning from the loop when finding the correct value. Thiswould also make "break" redundant.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, there's a parameter named `bankRequest`. Inside the method, you are assigning `bankRequest` a value.

By some, it is considered an ill approach to assign values to parameters within a method's body, as it is, at times, confusing. Some developers prefer always assuming that a parameter is never assigned any value during a method's run.

To avoid that, you can declare an alternative variable of type `BankDTO`:

```
BankDTO updatedRequest = bankRequest;
...
...
updatedRequest = reloadBankRequest(bankRequest, fee);
...
...
return updatedRequest;
```

Answer (score 1):

In java parameters are called by reference. In your case this means, if you change the object `bankRequest` it is not visible outside of the method `loadTariff`.

After the line `bankRequest = reloadBankRequest(bankRequest, fee);` the variable bankRequest points to a different object of BankDTO.

If you want to change internal values of bankRequest and use it after calling `loadTariff` you should do something like `bankRequest.loadRokaAndBankFee(fee)`.

Comment: Actually, parameters are passed by value in Java. Do not confuse the notion of reference, with the notion of reference type.

Comment: passed by value but the value is a reference. One of the most common mistakes. It copies the address.

Answer (score 1):

Reassigning values to incoming parameters is not recommended. **Use temporary local variables instead.**

```
Example(s): 

public class Foo {
  private void foo(String bar) {
    bar = "something else";
  }
}
```

reference: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.1/rules/java/design.html

Answer (score 0):

**Reassigning values to the incoming parameters is not recommended. Use temporary local variable.**

```
public BankDTO loadTariff(BankDTO bankRequest, int[] executionLevels) {
    double[] fee = null;

BankDTO updatedBankRequest = bankRequest;

    for (int level : executionLevels) {

        fee = loadCokaAndBankFee(bankRequest,level);

        if (fee != null) { 
            updatedBankRequest = reloadBankRequest(bankRequest, fee);
            break; 
        }        }

    return updatedBankRequest;
}
```